# A question about brownian motions

Tags: pr.probability, brownian-motion

I would like to ask a question about Brownian motion:

Let $B$ be a standard brownian motion. How to show that $\mathbb P( \max\limits_{0 \leq s \leq t} B(s) \in (a,b) )$ decreases exponentially in t with a, b fixed?

Comment: $\max_{s\leq t}B(s)$ equals $\vert B(t) \vert$ in law. Is this enough to prove the result ?

Comment: Apparently, yes. We can estimate the integral over (a,b) of the |Y| where Y is of the normal law N(0,t) with t large.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The precise answer depends on the initial condition, let's assume you start the Brownian motion (with diffusion constant $D$) at time $t=0$ in some point $x_0\in(a,b)$, then you ask for the probability
$$P(t)=\mathbb P[ \max\limits_{0 \leq s \leq t} B(s) \in (a,b) ]$$ 
that the particle has not crossed the point $x=b$ for all times up to time $t$. The point $x=b$ functions as an absorbing boundary for the Brownian motion. The [survival probability](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/First-hitting-time_model) is given by
$$P(t)={\rm Erf}\,\left(\frac{b-x_0}{2\sqrt{Dt}}\right)$$
For large $t$ this decays as as $1/\sqrt t$,
$$P(t)=\frac{b-x_0}{\sqrt{\pi Dt}}+{\rm order}(1/t)$$
so much slower than exponentially.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer. I assumed that $B(0)=0$ (a standard BM). The answer seems correct but quit surprising to me at the first sight because I thought that the integral in $\mathbb R$ w.r.t. time $t$ of $P(t)$ is finite.